# Using a custom comparison function for BTreeSet and a foreign type

Tags: rust

As detailed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34028324/1830736), I'm using custom logic in a `BTreeSet` to automatically sort a foreign data type as elements are added to the container.  Note that the Data type is `use`d from another module in the actual implementation, so I can't just implement `Ord` for it, necessitating this approach.

I'm concerned that the iterator pipeline I'm using in `main()` is too complex and that the various `impl`s are just boilerplate for something that really boils down to a single line of actual desired logic.

Here's a [Rust Playground link](http://is.gd/2l3blt).

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::convert::{From, Into};
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::ops::Deref;

// Here's the original struct...
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Data(usize);

impl From<usize> for Data {
    fn from(i: usize) -> Self {
        Data(i)
    }
}

// And here's the wrapper type we'll use to sort it.
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
struct SortableData(Data);

impl Deref for SortableData {
    type Target = Data;
    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Data {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl From<Data> for SortableData {
    fn from(data: Data) -> Self {
        SortableData(data)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for SortableData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for SortableData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        (self.0).0.cmp(&(other.0).0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let source: [Data; 3] = [Data(9), Data(4), Data(2)];
    let sorted: BTreeSet<SortableData> = source.iter().cloned().map(|i| i.into()).collect();
    for d in sorted.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", **d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks basically how I would write it, very nice! I do have a few tiny nits.

1. I strongly dislike using `Deref` except when you have a smart pointer. [I fear](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/syntactic-sugar-for-delegation-of-implementation/2633?u=shepmaster) that using `Deref` to compose items is going to be the Rust equivalent of using inheritance for code reuse.

   Using `Deref` also can be a bit surprising, as *every* method is now available. Let's say that your `Data` struct has some more methods:

   ```
   impl Data {
       fn wow(&self) { println!("Wow") }
   }
   ```

   Now, your `SortableData` has those methods as well!

   ```
   for d in sorted.iter() {
       d.wow();
   }
   ```

   I much prefer to be explicit about it; I would implement `Borrow` instead.

   I don't believe this opinion to be 100% supported by the community, but I'm going to make my case where I can ^_^
2. When possible, I'd implement `From` / `Into` in both directions. This doesn't always make sense, but here it does.
3. There's no need to specify the type for `source` — type inference handles that just fine.
4. You could just map the `into` function directly: `.map(Into::into)`.
5. Instead of calling `iter` in the for loop expression, you can just take a reference.
6. `From` and `Into` are both part of the [prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html) and thus don't need to be `use`d again.

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

// Here's the original struct...
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Data(usize);

impl From<usize> for Data {
    fn from(i: usize) -> Self {
        Data(i)
    }
}

// And here's the wrapper type we'll use to sort it.
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
struct SortableData(Data);

impl From<Data> for SortableData {
    fn from(data: Data) -> Self {
        SortableData(data)
    }
}

impl From<SortableData> for Data {
    fn from(data: SortableData) -> Self {
        data.0
    }
}

impl Borrow<Data> for SortableData {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Data {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for SortableData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for SortableData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        (self.0).0.cmp(&(other.0).0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let source = [Data(9), Data(4), Data(2)];
    let sorted: BTreeSet<SortableData> = source.iter().cloned().map(Into::into).collect();
    for d in &sorted {
        let d: &Data = d.borrow();
        println!("{:?}", d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `impl From<SortableData> for Data` legal if `Data` isn't my type, but is defined in another module/crate?  (Then, neither the implemented trait nor the data is my own type, which I believe is disallowed.)

Comment: @thirtythreeforty [yes, it is](http://is.gd/M7QBkQ). The important thing is that the trait or *one* of the types must be owned by you.  Since you own `SortableData`, you should be good to go.

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes more sense and is less draconian of a restriction than I thought.